# Font-weight not propperly showing different pages

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

i'm walking into this weird thing where my footer is showing different font weights with the same CSS code.
It is built in wordpress.

The footer is the exact same code on all pages but only shows propperly on the homepage. The font-weight cannot go below 400 on all the pages beside the homepage, also changing the propperty in chrome dev tool does not work below 400?

Homepage: fixed

screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkwOa.jpg

CSS :

```
.footer-widgets {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

font-face :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Font-family code on the different pages are also not striped through or anything in the dev tool! So this means they are not being overwritten somewhere else

Comment: Hey Wesley, can you screen different screen (homepage and an other one) in order to see the difference and provide a snippet of your css code :) ?

Comment: Absolutely! Added them

Comment: it's really weird indeed ! It's exactly the same CSS.

Comment: Can you add your @font-face ?

Comment: @RémyTesta Yea i never ran into a problem like this! Edited with the font face link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put this link for your font :)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700|Work+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Work+Sans:300&display=swap use this it will work. If you have to use different font weight you have to choose from google font which weight you need as per screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probobly have some other css overrideing , this works however ( tested in chrome devtools)

font-weight: 100 !important;

Comment: Does it work on other pages? (Not the homepage). Because when i do this it doesn't actually work! It only works on the homepage

Comment: could be some font problem, does not work on other pages but if the custom font is removed then it works

Comment: I thought so aswell, but both the fonts seem to be the same and i have also added the font in my header just to be sure! Even when it's one of the default fonts wordpress has ( i believe )